# JavaFX - button size in percents

Tags: javafx

Is there any way to define the size for buttons (or any control) with a percentage and not a pixel value. I use `button.setPrefSize(20,10)`; if I resize the window, the buttons's size stays the same.

I am developing an application which runs on a Raspberry Pi and I plan to set a full-screen mode. I have this example code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;        
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class example extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setPrefSize(300,300);
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

If I run this code in my PC, it looks like this:

[image]

But when I run it in the Raspberry Pi with a smaller screen, the view looks like this:

[image]

(notice that the second image is really smaller from the firs and not the button is bigger nor on both is the button the same size i pixels)

On both, the button maintains the same size in pixels.

How can I set the button size in percents, so when I run it in Raspberry Pi (or the same when I resize the window), it will get the same size?

I don't want to make it with FXML.

Comment: For some scenarios there's `GridPane` with `Column/RowConstraints` and `percentWidth/Height`. You may need to add up to 2 more constraints each for every other child in case none of the bounds match the x/y coordinates of the other children...

Comment: please do some research before asking (don't see anything related to sizing in your code)

Comment: You cannot do it without FXML. You've even confirmed that in the title of your post; FXML controls use properties which are instances of JavaFX classes.

Comment: I'm already using grid pane in my real program but this helps only on where the controls are located percentage, not for the size of the controls itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use It:

```
    button.prefHeightProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(primaryStage.widthProperty(), 10.0));
    button.prefWidthProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(primaryStage.widthProperty(), 10.0));
```

Comment: wow, works but I'm not understanding it (how it works and what is bind and binding)can someone explain it for me? also, is there a more easy way?

Comment: If that's the only node in your `Scene` or if you do this to the root node, this is great. If your scene is going to more complicated, you should use layout nodes to render your view properly. I would follow some of fabian's suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

now I got an idea how to do it with grid pane,
just make a grid pan with an extra box for each control you wont to have,(for the control it's self, not for a pane in which the control leaves in), and set the controls pref size to  `Double.MAX_VALUE`, then adjust the size for the control with the box size by specifying the row and column percent size,
(`column.setPercentWidth(30);` `row.setPercentWidth(30);`),

to get it better to understand how to make with more than one control I made the example with 2 buttons
hare is the example

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class example extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        Button button2 = new Button();
        button2.setPrefSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.getChildren().addAll(button, button2);

        ColumnConstraints columnConstraints = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnConstraints.setPercentWidth(30);
        ColumnConstraints columnButton = new ColumnConstraints();
        columnButton.setPercentWidth(40);

        RowConstraints rowConstraints = new RowConstraints();
        rowConstraints.setPercentHeight(30);
        RowConstraints rowButton = new RowConstraints();
        rowButton.setPercentHeight(40);

        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(columnConstraints, columnButton, columnConstraints, columnButton, columnConstraints);
        gridPane.getRowConstraints().addAll(rowConstraints, rowButton, rowConstraints);
        GridPane.setConstraints(button, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(button2, 3, 1);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane);

        primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

hares an example run with full screen
[image: hares an example run with full screen]

and hare the same run after resizing
[image: and hare the same run after resizeing]